# CRJAZ2384E Cannot connect to the repository at URL

Tags: eclipse, jazz

When I try to connect to the Repository from Eclipse, I get the following error,

CRJAZ2384E Cannot connect to the repository at URL "https://clm.product.org/ccm", see the nested exception for more details. For more details, open the help system and search for CRJAZ2384E.
CRJAZ2384E Cannot connect to the repository at URL "https://clm.product.org/ccm", see the nested exception for more details. For more details, open the help system and search for CRJAZ2384E.
  Invalid Padding length: 207
  Invalid Padding length: 207

Can anyone provide some inputs?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the Eclipse Indigo version which I was using. When I downloaded a new version of Indigo and configured it with Jazz, all went well.