# CRJAZ2384E Cannot connect to the repository at URL. Invalid Padding Length

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rtc, jazz, ibm-jazz

When I try to connect to the Repository from Eclipse, I get the following error,

```
CRJAZ2384E Cannot connect to the repository at URL "https://clm.product.org/ccm", see the nested exception for more details. 
For more details, open the help system and search for CRJAZ2384E. 

CRJAZ2384E Cannot connect to the repository at URL "https://clm.product.org/ccm", see the nested exception for more details. 
For more details, open the help system and search for CRJAZ2384E. 
Invalid Padding length:
```

Note: It was working till yesterday. Suddenly it got disconnected and began showing up the above error

I installed new version of Eclipse too and tried to connect. But it still did not connect.

Request help please.

Answer (score 0):

It can depends on your OS and on the java used (the one from RTC, IBM jre), or an external one (as in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/134649/crjaz2384e-cannot-connect-to-the-repository-when-using-oracle-java-17-u45))

An `Invalid padding length` error when trying to connect to an https url indicates an handshake issue ([like this one](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2506695) or [this one](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8013059))

> I noticed that the [bug suggested here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=2222432) relates to the Diffie-Hellman key exchange, so **I tried selecting a cipher which does not use Diffie-Hellman** (`-Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`) and the problem went away.

Depending on how your RTC server is installed, check with the RTC admin if that policy can be enforced.

Since the issue persists with a new Eclipse, it is unlikely that this [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25488817/6309) (about upgrading Eclipse) would help.

The [OP Stalwart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1522811/stalwart) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666148/crjaz2384e-cannot-connect-to-the-repository-at-url-invalid-padding-length/26669674?noredirect=1#comment41954213_26669674):

> I resolved this issue by **adding the path of JDK in the Target path** after clicking on properties

Comment: Thanks VonC. I resolved this issue by adding the path of JDK in the Target path after clicking on properties.

Comment: @Stalwart Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

In the Rational Software Architect JRE edit the java.security file and comment out the option jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21663610